# If $D$ is $\|.\|-$separable subset of $X$. Then $D$ is Suslin space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of $\|.\|-$separable subset of $X$.

Take $D=\overline{\text{co}}~\cup_nA_n$, then $D$ is $\|.\|-$separable subset of $X$.

**Question:**

Why $D$ is Suslin space ?